# How to detect V-if content was changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am trying to apply animation `width:20%` on `wrong` class when v-if condition becomes false , how can i watch v-if change .

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ok: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.ok = !this.ok;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    ok() {
      // apply animation after v-if is false
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.wrong {
  background-color: #fdd;
  transition: width 2s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="view1">
   <div v-if="ok">
    <p class="right">OK</p>
   </div>
   <div v-else>
    <p class="wrong">NO</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
</template>
```

Comment: You should put your jQuery logic into the `mounted` vue hook, but I don't really recommend to involve jQuery here.

Comment: Can you show use jQuery code ?

Comment: jQuery code removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS rather than jQuery. The trick is to have a width transition, and a delay in applying the width style. You listen to a change by using a `watch`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.view1',
  data: {
    ok: true,
    delayedReaction: null
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.ok = !this.ok;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    ok() {
      if (this.ok) {
        this.delayedReaction = null;
      } else {
        // nextTick didn't suffice
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.delayedReaction = {
            width: '20%'
          };
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.wrong {
  background-color: #fdd;
  transition: width 2s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="view1">
  <div v-if="ok">
    <p class="right">OK</p>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <p class="wrong" :style="delayedReaction">NO</p>
  </div>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>
```